# Fatal PHP-Error in roundcube (missing Mail_mimePart)

Tags: php, pear, roundcube

We have a roundcube instance on our ubuntu server.

Since yesterday, we are not able to send emails anymore. After hitting the send-button in roundcube, the "Nachricht wird gesendet..."-Message (E-Mail is being sent) loads endlessly.

After searching the logs, I found the error message:

```
[30-Jun-2015 10:33:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for Mail_mimePart::Mail_mimePart(), called in [***]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php on line 1288 and defined in [***]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime-decode/Mail/mimePart.php on line 127
[30-Jun-2015 10:33:50 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() in [***]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php on line 1289
```

It it still possible to sent E-Mails directly via SMTP / Dovecot, so everything should be fine on this side.

My first thought was to install the pear packages, but they seem to be correctly installed inside roundcube.

Stacktrace is:

```
[30-Jun-2015 11:52:26 UTC] Backtrace from warning 'Missing argument 1 for Mail_mimePart::Mail_mimePart(),
 called in [...]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php on line 1334 and 
defined' at [...]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime-decode/Mail/mimePart.php 127: [...]/roundcube/index.php 290 calling include_once() |
 [...]/roundcube/program/steps/mail/sendmail.inc 509 calling headers() |
 [...]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php 1101 calling encodeHeaders() |
 [...]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php 1314 calling encodeHeader() |
 [...]/roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php 1334 calling Mail_mimePart()
[30-Jun-2015 11:52:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mail_mimePart::encodeHeader() in [...]roundcube/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php on line 1335
```

Notes:

- Server is up-to-date.
- Composer was updated

Comment: Seems like yout pear 'mail_mime' package has been updated, and its version is not backwards compatible. Either revert to older version (if you know which one), or update your php code.

Comment: I already solved it earlier, but this is not incorrect, see my answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just completely reinstalled roudcube (User data was either in MySQL or Dovecot, so no data loss).

It was a similar problem as @Alex Chorry already pointed out in the comments. It was caused by composer updating the mail_mime package while installing a plugin (in my case it was globaladdressbook, but I've seen this problem also on other plugin). Also reverting the php wasn't working, as it resulted in a plugin error.

So to solve this problem, I completely ignored composer, and never installed it. I manually installed all the plugins as pointed out her on [github](https://github.com/JohnDoh/Roundcube-Plugin-Global-Address-Book):

> - Place this plugin folder into plugins directory of Roundcube
> - Add globaladdressbook to $config['plugins'] in your Roundcube config

Answer (score 1):

Unsure where to report but for the moment you can solve this by changing the line 75 in `/vendor/pear/mail_mime/Mail/mime.php` from `require_once 'Mail/mimePart.php';` to `require_once 'mimePart.php';`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation as the poster.  I had been (unsuccessfully) messing about with plugins and then I could no longer send mail.   roundcube/logs/error had the same message from when I tried to send.

The Roundcube Community Forum has a [solution](http://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=22760.0) that worked for me.

I removed the roundcube/vendor dir (actually, I did `mv vendor vendor_bak` just in case) and did `composer install` from the roundcube dir.

Suddenly I could send again.

Answer (score 0):

I removed these 3 lines from composer.json

```
    "pear/mail_mime": ">=1.8.9",
    "pear/mail_mime-decode": "~1.5.5",
    "pear/net_smtp": "dev-master",
```

I then ran  php composer.phar  update

Then I put the lines back, ran the update:
incc:/var/lib/roundcube#  php composer.phar  update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository http://pear.php.net                                                                                                 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)     - Installing pear/pear_exception (dev-master 8c18719)
    Cloning 8c18719fdae000b690e3912be401c76e406dd13b

- Installing pear/console_getopt (v1.4.1)
  Loading from cache
- Installing pear/pear-core-minimal (dev-master 0457483)
  Cloning 0457483add2e037a5e00eb186b9dce7ea3b49da2
- Installing pear/net_socket (dev-trunk bbe6a12)
  Cloning bbe6a12bb4f7059dba161f6ddd43f369c0ec8d09
- Installing pear/net_smtp (dev-master 3ef8150)
  Cloning 3ef8150ef230314f2a70e803e13a9926e432f7af
- Installing pear/mail_mime (dev-master 66b2a01)
  Cloning 66b2a01acabe0b8d0ce606833d5cefc1a49a8887
- Installing pear/mail_mime-decode (1.5.5.2)
  Downloading: 100%

And logged back into roundcube and I could send again.

I didn't really understand the author's answer but as I saw it could be to a rogue plugin (I have installed and removed a few) I thought I would try this out that worked.